# Orbital state vectors : elaboration needed on the position vector

Tags: artificial-satellite, software

I already asked here about how to calculate orbits of satellites programmatically then plot them on 2d plane, but my question was too broad.

I'm still on my journey to understand & pull such software out ; I learned that Orbital state vectors are the way to start plotting a certain celestial object's orbit, but I don't quite understand the parameters of the vector.

Needing R (position) & V (velocity) & T (time),

Since V can be fetched from dividing the differentiation of R/T.

But R is composed of (x,y,z), how can I calculate it with respect to the frame of reference (earth-centered equatorial system) ?

Am I moving on the right track ?

Comment: Do you just want to know how the orbit would look like, or do you want to find the position/velocity as a function of time?

Comment: I'm targeting the latter in order to have a real-time tracking map. Though ; I truly lack the resources & the knowledge to come up with that, and I can't waste peoples' time in here in infinite questions. I'll stick to static orbit display only ( your first suggestion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For plotting, it is easiest to compute the positions *and* the time as a function of the eccentric anomaly, as opposed to trying to compute position as a function of time.  You can compute the velocity as a function of the eccentric anomaly as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll research the eccentric anomaly, and see how it might serve me in completing my project.